# Thread 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, inputstream, input-buffer

I am reading bytes from Data. But am getting a crash after first iteration of while loop.

**Note: This is not index out of bounds issue.**

```
func readData(data: Data)
    {
        if isPacketRecieved == true
        {
            SocketManager.shared.connectionOpened()
            isPacketRecieved = false
        }
        // 1
        var packetBuffer = Data()

        // 2
        bufferManager.writeDataToBuffer(data: data)

        // 3
        while(bufferManager.getUnusedBufferSize() >= MAX_PACKET_SIZE){

            // 3.1
            packetBuffer.removeAll()
            packetBuffer = bufferManager.readDataFromBuffer(size: Int(MAX_PACKET_SIZE))
            self.parsePacket(data: packetBuffer)

        } // -- while

    }


func parsePacket(data: Data){

if data.count == MAX_PACKET_SIZE {

let dataHeader = data[0 ..< 10] ===> // here I am getting crash
let dataBody = data [10 ..< 30]
guard let dataStreamHeader = SocketStream(data: dataHeader) else {return}
guard let dataStreamBody = SocketStream(data: dataBody) else {return}
// ź

guard let exchange = dataStreamHeader.readString(1) else {
    return
}
guard  let scripCode = dataStreamHeader.readInt() as? Int32 else {
    return
}
guard let time = dataStreamHeader.readInt()  as? Int32  else {
    return
}
guard let type = dataStreamHeader.readString(1) else {
    return
}
print("Packet Type :: \(type)")
let responseHeader = ResponseHeaderPacket(exchangeCode: exchange, scripCode: Int(scripCode), time: Int(time), type: type)

var pckt: BroadcasterPacket!

switch type {
case ONE:
    var loginReq = sLoginRequest()
    let loginData = loginReq.sendAcknowledgementPacket()
    manager?.sendAcknowledgementData(data: loginData)

    break
case A :
    pckt = Packet_A(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case G :
    pckt = Packet_G(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case H :
    pckt = Packet_H(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case g :
    pckt = Packet_g(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case m :
    pckt = Packet_m(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case B,C,D,E,F :
    pckt = Packet_MarketDepth(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    manageDepthPacket(packet: pckt! as! Packet_MarketDepth)
    return
case Z :
    pckt = Packet_Z(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break
case X :
    pckt = Packet_X(stream: dataStreamBody, header: responseHeader)
    break

default:
    break
}
guard let packet = pckt else {
    return
}
    print("ScropCode :\(packet.header.scripCode)")
quoteObject(packet: packet)

}

}
```

Comment: Most likely `data` has less than 10 bytes in it.

Comment: What is `MAX_PACKET_SIZE`?

Comment: @Yonat MAX_PACKET_SIZE is number of bytes which I want to read from data which is 30.

Comment: @rmaddy No sir, Data is total 90 bytes

Comment: Look in the debug console for the complete error message. And add `print(data.count)` just before the line that crashes. What does it show just before the crash?

Comment: Debug console shows nothing and print(data.count) comes 30...which is my MAX_PACKET_SIZE